# UI tests failing in Xcode 14

Tags: uitest, xcode14

Failed to Error Domain=com.apple.dt.xctest.ui-testing.error Code=10001 "Application is not running"

All of the UI tests were working in Xcode 13 but once I updated to 14, they all failed. Also noted that all unit tests pass and the issue is only with UI tests. I've tried XCUIApplication launch but that didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error but only on a CI runner (Github Actions). What made it pass was adding `app.activate()` before `app.launch()` in the setUp func:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()

override func setUpWithError() throws {
    continueAfterFailure = false
    app.activate()
    app.launch()
}
```

Hope this helps!